# azure search - are datediff / dateadd functions available?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I would like to know if the SQL Functions (DateAdd / DateDiff) are available on Azure Search. I could not find examples / docs about it, but they exist on ODATA official doc:

http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RDA/jdbc/pg_sqldatefunctions.htm

In case they are not available, what is the recommended way for date diffs as filters (e.g Age gt 18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search does not currently support OData date functions. You can model this particular problem in one of two ways: Either store time spans of a particular unit as integers (for example, age in years), or model everything as DateTimeOffset and just compare between them. For example: `DateOfBirth lt 2000-07-03T00:00Z`

Comment: just a tip, please review the documentation and include which functions are not available / supported.

Comment: Unsupported features of OData filters
- Arithmetic expressions 
- Functions (except the distance and intersects geospatial functions) 
- any/all with arbitrary lambda expressions 

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#bkmk_unsupported

We'll be updating this article soon, so we'll look for ways to make this more obvious.